# Your build configuration targets an unsupported Application Binary Interface (ABI)

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

I am not able to upload .aab file in Google Play Console. Google Play Console is giving an error

`Your build configuration targets an unsupported Application Binary Interface (ABI). These ABIs are not currently used by active devices. To continue using automatic integrity protection, update your build configuration so that it only targets these Android ABIs: x86, x86_64, armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a. You can update your build configuration by following these steps.`

I tried to follow the given link
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#specify-abi
still not able to resolve the issue. I am already specifying ABI "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a" in my app `build.gradle` file. I also tried to follow this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/252706431/your-build-configuration-targets-an-unsupported-application-binary-interface-abi?hl=en but did not get any solution. I am using react-native version `0.70.6`, can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score -2):

Fixed that by adding

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
}
```

to the `defaultConfig` section of app/build.gradle

Comment: I have added your code still have the same issue.

Comment: @Shivam, I suggest you assemble an APK, decompile it with the apktool, and see which exact dependency ruins your build.